# Fopen or File_Put_Contents Timeout option?

Tags: php, timeout, fopen, file-put-contents

Really simple one, I just want to add a timeout in either fOpen or File_Put_Content
Currently it appears the timeout is set to 30 seconds.

This is way too long to wait, this file is writing a file out locally, if the file cannot be accessed or written then it needs to fire an error message off straight away not after 30 seconds.

I have tried

```
php.ini default_socket_timeout = 5   // Made no change
```

Inside PHP File:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout',2); // Made no change
```

Tried the following code:

```
                $context = stream_context_create(array('http'=> array(     'timeout' => 1.0,     'ignore_errors' => true, )));
                $fh = @file_put_contents($file, $string, false, $context);
```

Apart from writing a If statement and doing a countdown from X seconds and then doing a break to exit out of the loop, i am kinda running out of ideas.

I just want to create a text file with some content, if it cannot write the file out within a couple of seconds then to move on (So i can trigger a error)

```
 if (!is_resource($fh)) { 
// some error handling 
}
```

Been through the documentation and i seen nothing, Other then these two methods, is there any other option i can use to set a simple timeout

Comment: _"this file is writing a file out locally"_ - you mean you are writing to the local file system? Then what do you want with any _HTTP_ timeout, that would not even apply then ...?

Answer (score 0):

Use a different setting:

```
set_time_limit(10);
```

set_time_limit limits the maximum execution time of a script. If this is reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30 seconds.

Comment: Yes but this applied to the whole program, i just want it on the Fwrite or File_Put_Content function

Comment: @DaveHamilton The error that you want to trigger should it stop the execution of the script? Or do you plan to handle it and continue with the execution?

Comment: Handle it and continue with the execution, If it errored i wanted top write to the error_log and continue, because at the end of my code i have some error handling to display notifications to the user. the Fatal error stops the execution of the code.